# wxPython - Changing status bar text from a child process

Tags: wxpython

My code (Ubuntu 18.04, Python 2.7, wxPython 4) creates a user interface with a status bar and then launches a child process. The new process tries to update the status bar text, but the change doesn't appear in the status bar.

The sample code shows what I'm trying to accomplish:

```py
    import wx, multiprocessing

    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, title):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(300,200))
            self.sb = self.CreateStatusBar()
            self.sb.SetStatusText('Original text')
            self.Show(True)

    def doWork():
        print 'In doWork'
        print frame.sb.GetStatusText()
        frame.sb.SetStatusText('New stuff')
        print frame.sb.GetStatusText()

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=doWork, args=())
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(None, 'Status Text')
    p.start()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The `doWork` process can access and print the original status bar text and it appears that it was able to set the status text (based on the result of the second print).  But the text displayed in the status bar doesn't change.  Is there a way I can update the status bar text from a separate process?

Answer (score 1):

Gui programs run in their mainloop and I believe, updates must occur within the mainloop. (Someone may clarify here or indeed, tell me I'm wrong).

Usually the way to achieve this is to generate an event from `wx.lib.newevent` or use something like `pubsub`. These however are normally generated from with a `Thread` not a `Process`, again, someone may correct me (I'm as fuzzy as the next man on this).

See here: [Python multiprocessing, PyAudio, and wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924795/python-multiprocessing-pyaudio-and-wxpython)
and here: [wxpython 3.0 & multiprocessing - update GUI from background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667606/wxpython-3-0-multiprocessing-update-gui-from-background-process)
for background information

and here for a detailed resolution :https://wiki.wxpython.org/MultiProcessing

The answer appears to be to use a `Queue` from `multiprocessing` and use a `wx.Timer` to periodically check that queue for any updates.

I have knocked up a quick script to illustrate a solution with your code. At the least, it should be a reasonable starting point from which you can progress.
In addition to changing the status text initially, it also updates every 5 seconds, just to prove the point.

```
import multiprocessing
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(300,200))
        self.sb = self.CreateStatusBar()
        self.sb.SetStatusText('Original text')
        self.Show(True)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.process_timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.poll, self.timer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.process, self.process_timer)
        self.timer.Start(1000)
        self.process_timer.Start(5000)
        self.cnt = 0

    # Poll for a queue entry with which to update the statusbar
    def poll(self, event):
        print("Polling")
        if q.empty():
            return
        q_mess = q.get()
        self.sb.SetStatusText(q_mess)

    #Fire off a new process every 5 seconds to demonstrate the update
    def process(self, event):
        self.cnt += 1
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=doWork, args=(q,self.cnt))
        p.start()

def doWork(q,cnt=0):
    print ('In doWork')
    q.put("New status "+str(cnt))

q = multiprocessing.Queue()
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=doWork, args=(q,0))
app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Status Text')
p.start()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]